# Python continue for loop from file

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a code that generates characters from `000000000000` to `ffffffffffff` which are written to a file.
I'm trying to implement a check to see if the program was closed so that I can read from the file, let's say at `00000000781B`, and continue for-loop from the file.
The Variable "attempt" in (for attempt in `to_attempt`:) has tuple type and always starting from zero.

Is it possible to continue the for-loop from the specified value?

```
import itertools

f = open("G:/empty/last.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
rand_string = str(lines[0])
f.close()
letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'
print(rand_string)
for length in range(1, 20):
    to_attempt = itertools.product(letters, repeat=length)
    for attempt in to_attempt:
        gen_string = rand_string[length:] + ''.join(attempt)
        print(gen_string)
```

Comment: Please break down your explaination and question.

Comment: Also fix your code indentation please

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the value on a file to keep track of what value was last being read from. I'm assuming the main for loop running from 000000000000 to ffffffffffff is the `to_attempt` one. All you need store the value of the for loop in a file. You can use a new variable to keep track of it.

```
try:
    with open('save.txt','r') as reader:
        save = int(reader.read())
except FileNotFoundError:
    save = 0
#rest of the code
    for i in range(save,len(to_attempt)):
        with open('save.txt','r') as writer:
            writer.write(i)
        #rest of the code
```